# How to provide collection name in nodejs/mongoose/ for $out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, migrate

I have a field called `pin_count` which has a count of another field called `pins` but due to broken logic the count of both fields mismatched, so I am writing migration script using `migrate-mongo` and below is what I did. But not sure why it's not working.

I have tested below which is working fine:

```
db.pins.aggregate([
    { '$addFields': {
        'pin_count': { '$size': '$pins'}
    }},
    { "$out": "pins" }
]);
```

But, the same in migrate-mongo()(https://www.npmjs.com/package/migrate-mongo) plugin isn't working.

```
'use strict';

const BPromise = require('bluebird');
const types = ['pins`];

module.exports = {
  up(db) {
      return BPromise.resolve(types).mapSeries(col => {
          return db.collection(col).aggregate([
              { '$addFields': {
                  'pin_count': { '$size': '$pins'}
              }},
              { "$out": col }
          ]);
      });
  },

  /**
   * No need to have down script since this is a correction of the data
   */
  down: function (db) {

  }
};
```

Document structure:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId, "pins" : [ 'da', 'dal' ], "pin_count" : 4}
```

Comment: please add sample documents from your original collection

Comment: ```"_id" : ObjectId,
        "pins" : [
                'da', 'dal'
        ],
        "pin_count" : 4,
        ``` @felix

Comment: @chridam is not working any idea

Comment: Please add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, we don't know what `types` resolves to. Have you tried testing that pipeline on a separate test collection with some sample documents?

Comment: I tired ```db.pins.aggregate([
 { '$addFields': {
  'pin_count': { '$size': '$pins'}
    }},
    { "$out": "pins" }
]);``` which is working fine but not that one in question.

Comment: The problem with `$out`, how to provide it?

Comment: You are returning an aggregation cursor instead of a Promise as specified in the `migrate-mongo` library. To return a promise, chain the [**`toArray()`**](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/AggregationCursor.html#toArray) method on the `aggregate()` method i.e. `return db.collection(col).aggregate([ ... ]).toArray();`

Comment: Hey man! thanks so much!

Comment: Totally missed that one.